# NetLogo: Neet to set the variable's value to a random number within a range

Tags: range, global-variables, report, netlogo, probability

Dear NetLogo Community,

I am aiming to set a variable's value to a number between -1 and 1. I have tried the following code but in vain.

```
to xyz
[
set probability-of-wom compute-wom [-1 1]
if probability-wom > 0 [...]
]
end

to-report compute-wom -1 1
  report -1 + random-float (1 - -1)
end
```

probablity-wom is a global variable in this case.
Appreciate your support in advance.
Thank you.

Regards,
Shreesha

Answer (score 1):

Shreesha

Let's say you want to generate a random number between `lower` and `upper`.  Then your `compute-wom` would be

```
to-report compute-wom [lower upper]
  report upper - random-float (upper - lower)
end
```

In your case, you would

```
set probability-of-wom compute-wom -1 1
```

But a couple of comments. First, what you are generating here is a random number between two limits (as your title suggests), so calling it a probability could be misleading to anyone reading your code. Probabilities will normally be in the range from zero to one. If you really are just looking to do something with a 50% probability, you can simply say

```
if random-float 1 >= 0.5 [...]
```

Second, reporters should generally take variable arguments if they are to have arguments at all. Note that since you hard code -1 and 1 in the body of your `to-report compute-wom` reporter, passing them as arguments is redundant, and possibly misleading to anyone reading your code.

Comment: Hello Mr. Charles, Thanks for your answer. Probability here refers to that random number between -1 to 1 being a positive or a negative number. Because, the later part of the code has ifelse loop with specific commands that are to be executed if the number is negative or positive. Hopefully my explanation is better now to understand. Also, thanks for suggesting alternatives.